# django import-export error `has_errors()` is validating against Resource OR the whole model?

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I try to follow: https://github.com/bmihelac/django-import-export/blob/master/docs/getting_started.rst

I defined the resource as follows:

```
from import_export import resources
from core_backend.models.exhibitor import Exhibitor
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from import_export import fields


class ExhibitorResource(resources.ModelResource):
    email = fields.Field()

    class Meta:
        model = Exhibitor
        fields = ('id', 'stand_id', 'email', 'title')

    def dehydrate_email(self, exhibitor):
        email = User.objects.filter(id=exhibitor.user_id)[0].email
        return email
```

Then in shell I try:

```
import tablib
from import_export import resources
from core_backend.models.exhibitor import Exhibitor
from core_backend.models.exhibitor_resource import ExhibitorResource
my_res = ExhibitorResource()
my_res.fields
#{'email': <import_export.fields.Field: email>, u'id': <import_export.fields.Field: id>, 'title': <import_export.fields.Field: title>, 'stand_id': <import_export.fields.Field: stand_id>}
dataset = tablib.Dataset(['', '2', 'w@x.pl', 'fooo'],
                         headers=['id', 'stand_id', 'email', 'title'])
res = my_res.import_data(dataset, dry_run=True)
res.has_errors()
True
```

**What is the reason? The `has_errors()` is validating against Resource OR the whole model?**

My Resource definition is:

a) subset of fields of Model `Exhibitor`

b) with added extra field `email` not in `Exhibitor` class

UPDATE:

I run with `raise_errors=True`

```
res = my_res.import_data(dataset, dry_run=True,raise_errors=True)
```

It prints:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/andi/.virtualenvs/daftdjango/lib/python2.7/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 350, in import_data
    six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/Users/andi/.virtualenvs/daftdjango/lib/python2.7/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 335, in import_data
    self.import_obj(instance, row, real_dry_run)
  File "/Users/andi/.virtualenvs/daftdjango/lib/python2.7/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 201, in import_obj
    self.import_field(field, obj, data)
  File "/Users/andi/.virtualenvs/daftdjango/lib/python2.7/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 193, in import_field
    field.save(obj, data)
  File "/Users/andi/.virtualenvs/daftdjango/lib/python2.7/site-packages/import_export/fields.py", line 83, in save
    setattr(obj, self.attribute, self.clean(data))
  File "/Users/andi/.virtualenvs/daftdjango/lib/python2.7/site-packages/import_export/fields.py", line 51, in clean
    value = self.widget.clean(value)
  File "/Users/andi/.virtualenvs/daftdjango/lib/python2.7/site-packages/import_export/widgets.py", line 137, in clean
    return self.model.objects.get(pk=pk) if pk else None
  File "/Users/andi/.virtualenvs/daftdjango/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 151, in get
    return self.get_queryset().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/andi/.virtualenvs/daftdjango/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 307, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name)
DoesNotExist: Stand matching query does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old question but here a possible answer if someone get the same problem.  The reason why `Django` is raising this issue, is because the model `Exhibitor` has a field attached to a foreign key in `Stand` model. (I solved a similar issue in my project adding the corresponding value in the model).

For this case `stand_id` should exist in `Stand` Model:

Stand Model:

```
stand_id, my_column
2, my_value
```

Then we can use:

```
dataset = tablib.Dataset(['', '2', 'w@x.pl', 'fooo'],
                         headers=['id', 'stand_id', 'email', 'title'])
```

Since `stand_id` `2` exist, the error should be gone...